# Bootstrap responsive menu under floating sprite navigation

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, drop-down-menu

I created a bootstrap responsive menu and another subnavigaiton floating sprite menu.  This is all created in WordPress and Ultimatum Framework.  The problem is the when the browser window is reduced in size and the bootstrap menu activates the dropdown menu is under the sprited images and a lower embedded iframe YouTube video.  Is there a way to fix the dropdown menu so that it's above all of these elements.

Here is the code that I am using for the bootstrap dropdown menu:

```
.navbar .nav li.dropdown.open > .dropdown-toggle, .navbar .nav li.dropdown.active > .dropdown-toggle, .navbar .nav li.dropdown.open.active > .dropdown-toggle {
    background-color: #9c8aa5;
    color: #fff !important;
    -webkit-border-radius: 5px;
    -moz-border-radius: 5px;
    border-radius: 5px;
}
.navbar .nav > li > .dropdown-menu:after {
    border-bottom: 6px solid #ffffff !important;
}
.dropdown-menu {
    background-color: #fff !important;
}
.dropdown-menu > li > a:hover, .dropdown-menu > li > a:focus, .dropdown-submenu:hover > a, .dropdown-submenu:focus > a {
    text-decoration: none;
    color: rgb(255, 255, 255);
    background-color: #9C8AA5 !important;
    -webkit-border-radius: 5px;
    -moz-border-radius: 5px;
}
.dropdown-menu > li > a:hover, .dropdown-menu > li > a:focus, .dropdown-submenu:hover > a, .dropdown-submenu:focus > a {
    background-color: #9C8AA5;
    background-image: linear-gradient(to bottom, #9C8AA5, #9C8AA5);
    background-repeat: repeat-x;
    color: #FFFFFF;
    text-decoration: none;
}
.dropdown-menu > li > a {
    clear: both;
    color: #333333;
    display: block;
    font-weight: normal;
    line-height: 20px;
    padding: 3px 20px;
    white-space: nowrap;
}
.dropdown-menu > li > a {
    clear: both;
    color: #333333;
    display: block;
    font-weight: normal;
    line-height: 20px;
    padding: 3px 20px;
    white-space: nowrap;
}
.dropdown-menu .current_page_ancestor > a > span, .current-menu-item > a {
    color: white!important;
}
.dropdown-menu li.current-menu-item, .dropdown-menu li.current-menu-ancestor {
    background-color: #ffffff;
}
.dropdown-menu ul li.current-menu-item > a {
    color: #FFFFFF;
}
```

Here is the code that I am using for the floating sprite navigation:

```
.micrositescontainer {
    background: url('img/microsites_main_bkg.jpg');
}
.micrositestopnav .ultimatum-nav {
    float: right;
    position: relative;
    left: -50%;
    text-align: left;
}
.micrositestopnav .horizontal-menu ul li {
    border: none;
    padding: 0px;
    list-style: none;
    position: relative;
    left: 50%;
    display: block;
}
.micrositestopnav .menu-item-8449 a {
    background-image: url("img/micrositestopnav.png");
    background-position: 0 0;
    display: block;
    height: 125px;
    outline: medium none;
    padding: 0;
    text-indent: 100%;
    white-space: nowrap;
    overflow: hidden;
    width: 200px;
}
.micrositestopnav li.menu-item-8449.menu-item-object-page:hover > a, .micrositestopnav ul ul:hover > a, .micrositestopnav li.menu-item-8449.menu-item-object-page a:focus {
    background-image: url("img/micrositestopnav.png");
    background-position: 0 -125px;
    display: block;
    height: 125px;
    outline: medium none;
    padding: 0;
    text-indent: 100%;
    white-space: nowrap;
    overflow: hidden;
    width: 200px;
}
.micrositestopnav li.current-menu-item.menu-item-8449 > a, .micrositestopnav li.current-menu-ancestor.menu-item-8449 > a, .micrositestopnav li.current_page_item.menu-item-8449 > a, .micrositestopnav li.current_page_ancestor.menu-item-8449 > a {
    background-image: url("img/micrositestopnav.png");
    background-position: 0 -125px;
}
.micrositestopnav .menu-item-8453 a {
    background-image: url("img/micrositestopnav.png");
    background-position: -200px 0px;
    display: block;
    height: 125px;
    outline: medium none;
    padding: 0;
    text-indent: 100%;
    white-space: nowrap;
    overflow: hidden;
    width: 200px;
}
.micrositestopnav li.menu-item-8453.menu-item-object-page:hover > a, .micrositestopnav ul ul:hover > a, .micrositestopnav li.menu-item-8453.menu-item-object-page a:focus {
    background-image: url("img/micrositestopnav.png");
    background-position: -200px -125px;
    display: block;
    height: 125px;
    outline: medium none;
    padding: 0;
    text-indent: 100%;
    white-space: nowrap;
    overflow: hidden;
    width: 200px;
}
.micrositestopnav li.current-menu-item.menu-item-8453 > a, .micrositestopnav li.current-menu-ancestor.menu-item-8453 > a, .micrositestopnav li.current_page_item.menu-item-8453 > a, .micrositestopnav li.current_page_ancestor.menu-item-8453 > a {
    background-image: url("img/micrositestopnav.png");
    background-position: -200px -125px;
}
.micrositestopnav .menu-item-8456 a {
    background-image: url("img/micrositestopnav.png");
    background-position: -400px 0;
    display: block;
    height: 125px;
    outline: medium none;
    padding: 0;
    text-indent: 100%;
    white-space: nowrap;
    overflow: hidden;
    width: 200px;
}
.micrositestopnav li.menu-item-8456.menu-item-object-page:hover > a, .micrositestopnav ul ul:hover > a, .micrositestopnav li.menu-item-8456.menu-item-object-page a:focus {
    background-image: url("img/micrositestopnav.png");
    background-position: -400px -125px;
    display: block;
    height: 125px;
    outline: medium none;
    padding: 0;
    text-indent: 100%;
    white-space: nowrap;
    overflow: hidden;
    width: 200px;
}
.micrositestopnav li.current-menu-item.menu-item-8456 > a, .micrositestopnav li.current-menu-ancestor.menu-item-8450 > a, .micrositestopnav li.current_page_item.menu-item-8456 > a, .micrositestopnav li.current_page_ancestor.menu-item-8456 > a {
    background-image: url("img/micrositestopnav.png");
    background-position: -400px -125px;
}
.micrositestopnav .menu-item-8481 a {
    background-image: url("img/micrositestopnav.png");
    background-position: -600px 0;
    display: block;
    height: 125px;
    outline: medium none;
    padding: 0;
    text-indent: 100%;
    white-space: nowrap;
    overflow: hidden;
    width: 200px;
}
.micrositestopnav li.menu-item-8481.menu-item-object-page:hover > a, .micrositestopnav ul ul:hover > a, .micrositestopnav li.menu-item-8481.menu-item-object-page a:focus {
    background-image: url("img/micrositestopnav.png");
    background-position: -600px -125px;
    display: block;
    height: 125px;
    outline: medium none;
    padding: 0;
    text-indent: 100%;
    white-space: nowrap;
    overflow: hidden;
    width: 200px;
}
.micrositestopnav li.current-menu-item.menu-item-8481 > a, .micrositestopnav li.current-menu-ancestor.menu-item-8481 > a, .micrositestopnav li.current_page_item.menu-item-8481 > a, .micrositestopnav li.current_page_ancestor.menu-item-8481 > a {
    background-image: url("img/micrositestopnav.png");
    background-position: -600px -125px;
}
```

The beta site can be viewed at http://betabooks.matthewflint.com

I thank everyone for their time and consideration.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to bring the Bootstrap collapse menu forward by adding the following code to my css:

```
.nav-collapse, .nav-collapse.collapse {
    background-color: #f7f7f7;
    z-index: 999 !important;
}
```

Now it is displaying the menu above the other elements.  This may not be the best solution but it works for me.

Thank you.